# Swift use tesseract in broadcast extension over 50MB memory limits

Tags: ios, swift, ocr, tesseract, broadcast

I want use Broadcast extension and SwiftyTesseract to recognition text on screen,but when I load tessdata then will use over 50MB memory lead to crash.

Has any solution use over 50MB memory or let main app background handler?

```
func loadOCR(){
    swiftTesseract = SwiftyTesseract(language: .custom("jpn"), dataSource:Bundle.main, engineMode: .lstmOnly)
}
```